# Need to create duplicate Index to make query faster

Tags: sql-server, indexing, playframework, azure-sql-database

I have a weird situation that sometimes my web application (Running on Play 1.5 framework) stop fetching results to a particular query. So after keep trying few minutes, the web server returns timeout.

I am using SQL Azure database. So to fix this, I login to the SQL Sever Management Studio and create a copy of an existing table index because I know this particular index is very important for this query. It is a duplicate index in the same table. After that, when I refresh the web app, it gets results from database. So it seems that some how the existing index has been invalidated, so it is not used when a request come from the front end.

What is the reason for this? Why I had to create duplicate index to get results? Any reason why existing index get useless? This is happening randomly like once per week. So every time, I create a duplicate index to activate the use of this index.

Comment: The symptoms suggest parameter sniffing. Creating the redundant index invalidates existing cached plans so the query is recompiled the next time it is executed and uses the index if it useful for the supplied parameter values. If the query is not executed frequently, an `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` may be the solution or you could use the [Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store) to use a specific plan.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Dan. I will definitely have a look at that and let you know if it fix the issue :-)

Comment: Hi Dan, I still have question though. When the query is called through the web app and not responding, I ran the same query with same parameters, directly in the SQL Management Studio and it returns the results instantly. So my question is , if this is due to parameter sniffing, why SQL Management Studio runs the same query faster (using the correct execution plan)? But the web app doesn't run the same query with same parameters fast?

Comment: See [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html).

Comment: Thanks Dan, it has all the information I was looking for :-)